# How to check Chef license in Linux Server

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Sorry if this question is asked in past
How to check Chef license expiration  from Chef server.
Below is the version history of my chef environment.
Chef Server 12.18.14
Chef server is Linux with  3.10.0-1062.1.2.el7.x86_64  build

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/chef_license.html

Comment: I don't find License expiration date these in mentioned directories. Can we accomplish this with any utilities?